# Dynamically generate values in matrix and calculate using them

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, tikz-matrix, random-numbers

I am using the following code to generate a matrix filled with random values. I would like to use this matrix to explain how a convolution is applied to an image (specifically the mean), so that's what I'm trying to fill the output matrix with. I have not been able to reuse the values from the list to use in a pgfmath calculation, which is the main reason this hasn't worked. Any help is appreciated!

Thank you all in advance.

```
% tikzpic.tex
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}% 'crop' is the default for v1.0, before it was 'preview'
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,positioning,backgrounds,fit}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\setsepchar{;/,}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
            DA/.style={
                    fill,
                    opacity=0.2,
                    %rounded corners,
                    inner sep=-1pt,
                    line width=1pt,
                },
        ]

        \readlist\image{%
            \pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult;
            \pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult;
            \pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult;
            \pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult;
            \pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult;
            \pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult;
            \pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{random(0,255)}\pgfmathresult;
        }
        
        \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]}] (im) {
                \image[1,1]  &\image[1,2] &\image[1,3] &\image[1,4] &\image[1,5] &\image[1,6] &\image[1,7]\\
                \image[2,1]  &\image[2,2] &\image[2,3] &\image[2,4] &\image[2,5] &\image[2,6] &\image[2,7]\\
                \image[3,1]  &\image[3,2] &\image[3,3] &\image[3,4] &\image[3,5] &\image[3,6] &\image[3,7]\\
                \image[4,1]  &\image[4,2] &\image[4,3] &\image[4,4] &\image[4,5] &\image[4,6] &\image[4,7]\\
                \image[5,1]  &\image[5,2] &\image[5,3] &\image[5,4] &\image[5,5] &\image[5,6] &\image[5,7]\\
                \image[6,1]  &\image[6,2] &\image[6,3] &\image[6,4] &\image[6,5] &\image[6,6] &\image[6,7]\\
                \image[7,1]  &\image[7,2] &\image[7,3] &\image[7,4] &\image[7,5] &\image[7,6] &\image[7,7]\\
            };


        \node[right=.2em of im] (str) {\(\ast\)};

        \matrix (k) [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]}, right=.2em of str] {
                \frac{1}{9}&\frac{1}{9}&\frac{1}{9} \\
                \frac{1}{9}&\frac{1}{9}&\frac{1}{9} \\
                \frac{1}{9}&\frac{1}{9}&\frac{1}{9} \\
            };
        \node[right=.2em of k] (eq) {\(=\)};

        \matrix (imp) [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]}, right=.2em of eq] {
                1 & 4 & 3 & 4 & 1\\
                1 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 3\\
                1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1\\
                1 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1\\
                3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
            };
        \node[below=0.2em of im] (imlabel) {\(i_{mn}\)};

        \node (klabel) at (k|-imlabel) {\(k_{pq}\)};

        \node (conv) at (str|-imlabel) {\(\ast\)};
        \node (eqlabel) at (eq|-imlabel) {\(=\)};
        \node (implabel) at (imp|-imlabel) {\({im'}_{mn}\)};

        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \node[DA,blue,fit=(im-1-4)(im-3-6)](im_sub){};
            \node[DA,purple,fit=(imp-1-4)(imp-1-4)](imp_sub){};
            \node[DA,red,fit=(k-1-1)(k-3-3)](k_sub){};
        \end{scope}

        \draw[dashed, teal] (im_sub.north east) -- (k_sub.north west);
        \draw[dashed, teal] (im_sub.south east) -- (k_sub.south west);

        \draw[dashed, blue!80!black] (k_sub.north east) -- (imp_sub.north west);
        \draw[dashed, blue!80!black] (k_sub.south east) -- (imp_sub.south west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: randomly filled matrix with kernel and (incorrectly) filled output]

Comment: I want to verify my understanding of your problem: You want to use the values of the nodes in matrices `im` and `k` to compute the values of `imp` by applying a certain formula?

Comment: I don't know how `listofitems` work but I'm pretty sure, you can't use `\pgfmathparse` and `\pgfmathresult` that way. The list is still not constant (do `\image[1,1] \image[1,1]` and see two different values) and secondly, you won't be able to use `\image[1,1]` inside of `\pgfmathparse` because it will contain `\pgfmathparse` (if it even is expandable). You will to actually pre-evaluate the values and only store them in the list and then maybe use `\itemtomacro`. That said, since PGFMath does have arrays, too, you might not even need `listoftimes`.

Comment: @DanielN yes exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a PGFmath and `\fpeval` solution (just for adding nine numbers and dividing by 9) that uses a PGFMath array.

However, since I let PGFmath evaluate this array once (because we want fixed numbers) this is stored not as a comma-separated list (of comma-separated lists) anymore but in its internal format (which using braces to group items). To access this again, we need to use `\pgfmatharray@`, unfortunately.

This is done by `\pgfmathtwoarray` which is *not* expandable but returns the result in `\pgfmathresult`. This can be used to be printed or to be used inside `\fpeval`.

---

I've adjusted some settings to the matrix so that the delimiters are placed more nicely around your matrices.

Horizontal alignment of the numbers could be achieved by using `anchor=base east` for the nodes inside the matrices and filling decimal places with `0` (via PGFmath or `siunitx` or …).

---

For a easier access to 49 values, I'd just store them in macros/value-keys where they can be directly access by their index but that's a whole different approach.

While `\fpeval` supports tuples, I didn't see any information in the manual about accessing their values. This probably will need `l3fparray`/`l3intarray` which provides expandable access to their array's values.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
% \usepackage{xfp}% possibly necessary for older distributions
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,positioning,backgrounds,fit}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\repeatMe[2]{%
  \ifnum#1=0 \expandafter\@gobble\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
    {#2\expandafter\repeatMe\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}{#2}}}
\newcommand*\pgfmathtwoarray[3]{
  \pgfmatharray@{#1}{\pgfinteval{#2-1}}%
  \pgfmatharray@{\pgfmathresult}{\pgfinteval{#3-1}}}
\newcommand*\tikzbuildmatrix[3]{%
  \repeatMe{#1}{%
    \repeatMe{#2}{%
      \node[name=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn]{#3};
      \unless\ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=#1 \expandafter\pgfmatrixnextcell\fi}
   \unless\ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=#2 \expandafter\pgfmatrixendrow\fi}
\pgfmatrixendrow}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    DA/.style={
        fill,
        opacity=0.2,
        %rounded corners,
        inner sep=-1pt,
        line width=1pt,
    },
    every left delimiter/.append style={xshift=.3333em},
    every right delimiter/.append style={xshift=-.3333em},
    every outer matrix/.append style={inner sep=+0pt},
]

\pgfmathsetmacro\image{{% this % is important here
    {random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255)},
    {random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255)},
    {random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255)},
    {random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255)},
    {random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255)},
    {random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255)},
    {random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255)}}}
\matrix [left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]},nodes={anchor=base}] (im) {
  \tikzbuildmatrix{7}{7}
    {\pgfmathtwoarray{\image}{\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}{\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}\pgfmathresult}
};

\node[right=.2em of im] (str) {\(\ast\)};

\matrix (k) [left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]}, right=.2em of str] {
  \tikzbuildmatrix{3}{3}{$\frac{1}{9}$}};
\node[right=.2em of k] (eq) {\(=\)};

\matrix (imp) [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]}, right=.2em of eq,
  row 1 column 4/.style={nodes={fill=purple!20, alias=imp_sub}}] {
    \tikzbuildmatrix{5}{5}{
      \gdef\solution{0}%
      \foreach[expand list] \ROW in {\pgfmatrixcurrentrow,...,\inteval{\pgfmatrixcurrentrow+2}}{
        \foreach[expand list] \COL in {\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn,...,\inteval{\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn+2}}{
          \pgfmathtwoarray{\image}{\ROW}{\COL}%
          \xdef\solution{\fpeval{\solution+\pgfmathresult}}
        }
      }
      \fpeval{round(\solution/9,2)}
  }};
\node[below=0.2em of im] (imlabel) {\(i_{mn}\)};

\node (klabel) at (k|-imlabel) {\(k_{pq}\)};

\node (conv) at (str|-imlabel) {\(\ast\)};
\node (eqlabel) at (eq|-imlabel) {\(=\)};
\node (implabel) at (imp|-imlabel) {\({im'}_{mn}\)};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node[DA,blue,fit=(im-1-4)(im-1-5)(im-1-6)(im-1-6)(im-2-6)(im-3-6)](im_sub){};
    \node[DA,red,fit=(k-1-1)(k-3-3)](k_sub){};
\end{scope}

\draw[dashed, teal] (im_sub.north east) -- (k_sub.north west);
\draw[dashed, teal] (im_sub.south east) -- (k_sub.south west);

\draw[dashed, blue!80!black] (k_sub.north east) -- (imp_sub.north west);
\draw[dashed, blue!80!black] (k_sub.south east) -- (imp_sub.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: The `\solution` macro is handled globally which might be a problem since it could be an already existing macro or environment. Either change the name or let me implement that double loop without grouping.

Comment: I like the new delimiter spacing! You were missing a `\usepackage{xfp}`, but otherwise it works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: @Dexterous The `xfp` isn't necessary anymore for an uptodate LaTeX distribution but, yes, for older you will need it. The new spacing works by eliminating the inner seps for the matrix node (but not the nodes themselves) and shifting them inside so that they ignore the inner xsep of the nodes.